# Stored Procedure taking a long time to return in Controller but not in Query Analyzer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure that I'm running in my *ASP.Net MVC 4* application.  The procedure does a lot of processing of records and packages up the records in a nice result set.  When I run this sproc in the *Query Analyz*er it **returns the data in 0 seconds**.  However, when I run the following code in the *Debugger* it takes **8-10 seconds to return**.

```
EvalStatus = db.Database.SqlQuery<EvaluationStatus>(
"exec [pro].sp_PROLeaderResultsGrid @schoolID, @leaderID, @blnAdmin",
 new SqlParameter("schoolID", leader.SchoolID),
 new SqlParameter("leaderID", leader.ID),
 new SqlParameter("blnAdmin", LeaderViewModel.IsAdmin)).ToList();

LeaderViewModel.EvaluationStatus = EvalStatus;
```

The EvaluationStatus is just a bunch of strings and integers in the order of the resultset from this procedure.

```
public class EvaluationStatus : IEvaluationStatus
{
    public string TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherStatus { get; set; }
    public string Actions { get; set; }
    public string ProLeaderStatus { get; set; }
    public string ProLeaderID { get; set; }
    public string ProLeaderName { get; set; }
    public string FinalLeaderName { get; set; }
    public string FinalLeaderStatus { get; set; }
    public string FinalTeacherStatus { get; set; }
    public string MenuActions { get; set; }
    public int LeaderKey { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm missing that would cause this code to take 8-10 seconds when running from the site?

Some other information.  I am using Entity Framework for most of my application except for this call.  I have not added this stored procedure to the .edmx.

Comment: This may be way off, but I'll post anyway, just in case. We recently encountered a major slowdown running a stored proc on SSMS vs. debugging. Come to find out, it was due to not having ARITHABORT turned on. Once we used `SET ARITHABORT ON`, the stored proc began returning very quickly in both places. Read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx) for more.

Comment: @JohnDubya - interesting.  I will float this past some of the DB minded folks to see what they know about this.

Comment: @JohnDubya - I tried adding that to my sproc last night and it appeared to be the answer!  However, this morning, the sprocs without the ARITHABORT were also running quickly this morning.  Do you know why that might be happening?  My guess is this afternoon I will see issues relating to this occurring again.

Comment: webdad3 - in our case, it appeared that since ARITHABORT was off on our production server, certain features of SQL Server (like performing queries on tables which had indexes on computed columns or indexed views) do not work, according to the documentation page I linked to above. Once we turned it on, SQL Server began using those indexes, which greatly sped up our queries. Do you have a similar situation? [Here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/why-would-set-arithabort-on-dramatically-speed-up-a-query) is some more info about the ARITHABORT issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding the "SET NOCOUNT ON" clause into your proc. With that, the proc won't send signals to ADO.Net each time a T-SQL statement is executed inside the proc. That might fix the issue.

If it continues being slow, you could switch this proc to a standard ADO.Net proc call, and set the SqlConnection PacketSize property to something between 3000 and 8000. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.packetsize.aspx

Also, keep in mind that the debugger execution time is not a good measure anyway, since the debugger itself makes things slower (very slow sometimes). Run the same code on Release mode and time-measure logic (with TimeSpans or whatever) to know the real execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  SET NOCOUNT ON is already there.  I did change it to release mode and it takes the same amount of time...  I'll check out your packetsize property suggestion.

Comment: It might be too late for this, but also the query analyzer uses different default connection options than when called from .Net. Procs execution plan get cached per 'connection', and if you change a single connection option, the execution plan is regenerated. That could mean that .Net might using a bad exec plan, while your query analyzer is using a better exec plan. Clear your server proc cache and check if now the query analyzer and .Net performs with the same performance (either good or bad, but consistent)